# How to make scientific notation "E" go away in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/45190976?hl=en

I tried doing what the above article stated, but it didn't work. Now, to give a clearer picture of what I'm dealing with:

In the first cell, this command is written: =ARRAYFORMULA(3/2^(SEQUENCE(100,1,1,1)))

An under it, there is a bunch of cells occupied with quite small numbers. Eventually, these numbers are so small they are written as a 0. If I press on the cell, the number written with the scientific notation appears. How do I make this go away. Can I increase the spreadsheet's limit of digits in a cell for example?

Answer (score 0):

In Google sheets select the cell the Format → Number then instead of Automatic, select Number and the result will be properly formatted.

[image]

Comment: I think I've tried this, or something similar, previously. Trying it now, the same result came. The zero is turned into a 0.00, but all the decimals are not showing themselves. If I hover over it, that same number with the scientific notation is showing.

Comment: What then is the true value you are trying to format?

Comment: There is a display limit of 30 decimals for a number. Since your results are 10^-30 and smaller it won't show number with decimals.